# Separate horizontal edge loops from a mesh and adjust the transform of each independently using Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, procedural

I have a subdivided cube into horizontal levels. With geometry nodes I want to separate all horizontal edges from the mesh and each other so I can adjust the transform of each level.

Here is an image of what i want to achieve.
[image]

In the image above, i have the horizontal edges/loops selected on the left mesh and the result i want is on the right. I want to separate the edges / loops and move them separately to the right and be able to adjust the transform of each edge loop

Comment: what do you mean with "i can adjust the transform of each level"?  can you show us the end result you wanna achieve?

Comment: So in the image above, I have the horizontal edges/loops selected on the left. The result is on the right. I want to separate the edges and move them separately to the right and be able to adjust the transform of each edge loop.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe geometry nodes has a conception of edge loops.  Additionally, "horizontal" isn't always well-defined for every mesh.  However, we can identify the loops in which you're interested, in the mesh in which you're interested, by a set of particular qualities: 1, the faces that they join are both perpendicular to the object up/down vectors; 2, the faces they join are coplanar.  We can select these edges and only these edges by capturing the face normal and the edge angle, and then separating edges that meet both of those criteria:

[image]

What we want to do with these edge loops is now up to us.  Different transformations are different operations.  Your picture suggests you're interested in shearing these edges, which we can do by translating in some axis on the basis of height times some constant:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Select the edges you want to manipulate, press P (Separate Elements Menu) > Selection.

[image]

Then in Edit mode for that new object, go into side or front view, and then Shear (Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S) to transform the loops like in the image.
[image]

Comment: i am not sure, but i think she wants a geometry nodes solution because of the tag...

Comment: @Jakemoyo Yes Chris is correct, sorry I should have added geometry nodes in my question instead of just that tag :( However i never knew you could use Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S to shear like that so thank you for that tip :D